# .htaccess: How can I keep the redirection and remove the subdirectory path from the urls please?

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I am trying to direct traffic to a subdirectory using .htaccess
The subdirectory is: /Release2/code.

The following is successfully redirecting but its is not hiding /Release2/code from the urls

```
RewriteEngine on 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?mysite\.com$ 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/Release2/code
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /Release2/code/$1 [L]
```

Comment: What URL are you entering in browser to test and what error do you get?